# How to build and package a Talend 7 Job with Maven?

Tags: maven, talend

If you build a job with Talend DI (commercial version) you can build the job with the "Add maven script" option:

[image]

This will produce a maven project which looks like this one:

[image]

How can you actually package the actual job using the command line and maven?

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the command line / shell first.

Then you will need to turn off the signature profile in the pom.xml file of the project of the actual job. Below is an example of where you can find the pom.xml in the folder structure:

[image]

Here is the relevant code to do that:

```
<profile>
  <id>signature</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault><!-- Change from true to false -->
  </activation>
  ...
```

Finally you will need to execute the *package* maven command and specify another repository where you can find specific Talend plugins which you cannot find in the central Maven repository. The actual command which worked for me was:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=D:\Talend_7.1.1\studio\configuration\.m2\repository -Dcommandline.skip=true package
```

Note also the `Dcommandline.skip=true` parameter which is necessary, because you are not executing the maven package command inside of Talend's command line.